# Ajax vs separate pages: how to deal with pressing 'back'?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, back

In order to avoid unnecessary reloading of entire pages, I use Ajax to go from one step to another in a multi step (or multi 'page', from the user experience point of view) process.

Works all fine. However, technically they're staying on the same single page (and keeping the same URL) during the entire process. I have 'back' buttons in my layout to go back to the previous stap, but if the visitor press his browser's 'back' button, I'm screwed.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: `history.pushState`? `window.onbeforeunload`?

Answer (score 0):

Sammy.js lets you use hash routing which is currently the best way to do a single page application that supports the back button

Answer (score 0):

History.js is your best bet for making your code run across most used web browsers: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What I always go for, is setting up a client side URL Router.
I've tried a few routers but I always come back to [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) because it's the most flexible [of the ones I've tried].
[Here is a little article](http://hjortureh.tumblr.com/post/23095099687/backbone-js-routing-made-simple) I found about the backbone.js router.

Another thing that is nice with the backbone.js router is:

> For browsers which don't yet support the History API, the Router
>   handles graceful fallback and transparent translation to the fragment
>   version of the URL.